# media-uploader insert into post is not inserting into text field

Tags: php, wordpress, customization

I have created a plugin for custom logo and its working fine, but when I tried to add this functionality into my exiting theme options its not working.

I have this js code.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
jQuery('#upload_logo_button').click(function() {
formfield = jQuery('#eo_theme_options[logo]').attr('name');
tb_show('', 'media-upload.php?type=image&amp;TB_iframe=true');
return false;
});
window.send_to_editor = function(html) {
    imgurl = jQuery('img',html).attr('src');
    jQuery('#eo_theme_options[logo]').val(imgurl);
    tb_remove(); 
}
});
```

and this is html structure,

```
<div class="grid col-620 fit">
<input id="eo_theme_options[logo]" class="regular-text" type="text" name="eo_theme_options[logo]" value="" placeholder="Custom Theme Logo"> <input id="upload_logo_button" type="button" value="Upload Image" class="button-secondary">
<label class="description" for="eo_theme_options[logo]">Enter your logo URL here.</label></div>
```

and this is php code which generates html,

```
protected function text( $args ) {

    extract( $args );

    $value = ( !empty( $this->eo_options[$id] ) ) ? ( $this->eo_options[$id] ) : '';
    $upload = (!empty($options)) ? '<input id="upload_logo_button" type="button" value="'.esc_attr($options).'"  class="button-secondary"/>' : '';

    $html = '<input id="' . esc_attr( 'eo_theme_options[' . $id . ']' ) . '" class="regular-text" type="text" name="' . esc_attr( 'eo_theme_options[' . $id . ']' ) . '" value="'. esc_html( $value ) . '"
    placeholder="' . esc_attr( $placeholder ) . '" /> '.$upload.'
    <label class="description" for="' . esc_attr( 'eo_theme_options[' . $id . ']' ) . '">' . esc_html( $description ) . '</label>';

    return $html;
}
```

My media up-loader is working fine, but its not inserting into the text field `name=eo_theme_options[logo]`

I tried everything and every thing is working fine only just instead inserting into post which should post into this,

[image]

so what problem could it be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may seem silly, but when I've done this in the past I've had to make sure the image I'm inserting is linking to "media file" so there is actually a path to the image being returned.  So click "upload image", then find the image you want, make sure it's linking to "media file", and then "insert into post".

A better approach, in my opinion, is to store the ID of the image in a hidden field, and show a thumbnail of the logo.  You can do a lot more if you have the ID of the image, over using the path of the image.

**UPDATE**

Remove the brackets inside the input's ID tag...

```
$html = '<input id="' . esc_attr( 'eo_theme_options[' . $id . ']' ) . '"
```

to

```
$html = '<input id="' . esc_attr( 'eo_theme_options_' . $id ) . '"
```

Comment: the images is linked to media files, that is working properly there is no problem, I also upload a file and then try to insert into post but thats not working, also try to insert existing media files that I already uploaded but still not worked.

there might be problem somewhere else, I have all the setup according to as it should be, but its not working as it should be.

and you only just give a opinion not any example or mistake or error.

Comment: Well thank you very much, that helped me. :)

but I didn't thought that it could be the problem. because its doesn't seems like to a problem, because its still working in my plugin with the same procedure method `eo_options[id]` but why it was not working in theme I don't know. 
well thanks a lot. :)

Comment: you can also support my question, if you know what I mean please :)